# MYSQL return rows with number of column relationships in another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table `categories` and table `posts` . I want to return categories that have more than 3 posts.

My query

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_title`, COUNT(posts.post_id) as total_posts 
FROM (`categories`) 
JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`category_id` = `categories`.`category_id` 
HAVING `total_posts` > 3 
ORDER BY `categories`.`date_created` desc
```

it returns just 1 row.. What is the correct way to do this type of query without using 2 queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is making use of a MySQL feature called "hidden columns" and you might not even know it.  This is because your query is referencing elements, such as date_created, which should be aggregated but are not ("should" here means according to the SQL standard and most other databases).

The problem with your query is that it is missing the group by.  An alternative way of writing this is with the aggregation in a subquery, *before* joining to category:

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_title`, total_posts 
FROM `categories` JOIN
     (select categoryid, COUNT(posts.post_id) as total_posts
      from `posts`
      group by categoryid
      having count(*) > 3
     ) pc
     ON `pc`.`category_id` = `categories`.`category_id`
ORDER BY `categories`.`date_created` desc
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is this query with subquery better than just adding `GROUP BY` to my original?

Comment: @CyberJunkie . . . Your ORDER BY clause uses a column that is not aggregated or in the GROUP BY clause.  This is acceptable in MySQL, but not in any other database.  A better version would be by saying "ORDER BY MIN(categories.date_created)" or something like I put here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `group` the items by category.

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_title`, COUNT(posts.post_id) as total_posts 
FROM (`categories`) 
JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`category_id` = `categories`.`category_id` 

GROUP BY `categories`.`category_id`

HAVING `total_posts` > 3 
ORDER BY `categories`.`date_created` desc
```